# how to work with my server and push notification to iphone device

Tags: iphone

I do have `server` which need to interact with `apple push notification server` [`APNS`] and from there it need to send to my `device`.

I am controlling version's in my `server`.  Do i need to write any code in my `server` side.

or just register with my server `SSL certificate` and `provision Profile` to `APNS`. and with `Device Token`

can any one advice me

I need to interact data from my `server` and `APNS` from there to device

I am controlling version number in `server` any changes in version number from 1 to 2  it need to send `APNS` from there it need to send my `device`.

I do not want to use any other third party to interact

And Server is developed into asp.net using c# [sharp] language

Comment: You should research the APNS again to know the answer of your question. You should follow this [tutorial] (http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to do some php scripting in the server side.and also You have to register and send and recieve the messages from the server,
in the appdelegate you have to use the delegate methods 
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

and in that you have to take devicetoken ,and send it to your server code,and then recieve the success in

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
  {
  and do the alerting in that method

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure you will need to write code, if you are using PHP, you could use http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/

Comment: my server scripting is written in ASP.net c# language